# Two div side by side and clearfix the flex for third div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to put third div under, not the side. But I couldn't make it properly. How can I achieve right clearfix/clear the flex apply and put the third div under that two divs.

```css
.cards {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
}

header {
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
}

main {
  width: 60%;
  background: blue;
}

#footer {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
            <header>
            </header>
            <main>
                <h1>TOPIC</h1>
                <nav>
                    <a href="">Example</a>
                    <a href="">Example</a>
                </nav>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <td>Example
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </main>
           <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
```

You can check the snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS grid as well:

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "header main"
    "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: red;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: blue;
}

#footer {
grid-area: footer;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h1>TOPIC</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Example</a>
            <a href="">Example</a>
        </nav>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Example</th>
                <td>Example</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Example</th>
                <td>Example
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Example</th>
                <td>Example</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Example</th>
                <td>Example</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```